# Building an email body

Tags: c#

So here we are, using a `StringBuilder` to build an email body. I know there's a lot on StackOverflow and endless debate/discussion around how best to concatenate strings.

- Can this be done in fewer lines of code in C#?
- Can this be done better using templating?

My goals are readability and maintainability.

```
StringBuilder msgBody = new StringBuilder();
msgBody.AppendLine("Deleted Order Item Information");
msgBody.AppendLine("------------------------------------");
msgBody.AppendLine();
msgBody.AppendLine("Delete Date:    {0}".FormatWith(orderDetail.DeletedDate.FormatDateTime(dtFormat)));
msgBody.AppendLine("Delete Comment: {0}".FormatWith(orderDetail.DeletedComment));
msgBody.AppendLine();
msgBody.AppendLine("Order #:        {0}".FormatWith(order.ID.ToString()));
msgBody.AppendLine("Order Date:     {0}".FormatWith(order.SubmitDate.FormatDateTime(dtFormat)));
msgBody.AppendLine("Order Name:     {0}".FormatWith(order.Name));
msgBody.AppendLine("Order Comment:  {0}".FormatWith(order.Comment));
msgBody.AppendLine("Department:     {0}".FormatWith("{0} - {1}".FormatWith(orderDetail.Department, orderDetail.DepartmentDesc)));
msgBody.AppendLine();
msgBody.AppendLine("Item Number:    {0}".FormatWith(orderDetail.StockNumber));
msgBody.AppendLine("Quantity:       {0}".FormatWith(orderDetail.Quantity));
msgBody.AppendLine("Rush:           {0}".FormatWith((orderDetail.Rush.ToYesNo())));
msgBody.AppendLine("Item Name:      {0}".FormatWith(item.Name));
msgBody.AppendLine("Item Desc:      {0}".FormatWith(item.Description1));
msgBody.AppendLine("                {0}".FormatWith(item.Description2));
msgBody.AppendLine("Stock:          {0}".FormatWith((orderDetail.Stock.ToYesNo())));
msgBody.AppendLine("Item Comment:   {0}".FormatWith(orderDetail.Comment));
```

Answer (score 6):

I have used one template engine in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) by name [DotLiquid](https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-for-Developers) to resolve similar problems.

1. Readability: You **have to extract your message template from the code** to separate file. The template itself will lives its own life, usually independently from the code.
2. Maintainability:

   - *Collect all required parameters and conditions in one place*. Having conditions in your message tends to be next step in real message processing. By the way, anonymous classes from DotLiquid work well with your [linq](/questions/tagged/linq).
   - Then: template processing, message composing, and and putting it to queue to sent it. Sending operation itself could be time consuming and quite tricky

Thus I have handled *hundreds* of template based messages with rich HTML per day. Obviously, if you're going to write next smtp monster,  you'll write a more perfomance optimal solution. But using such template engine is good place to start.

And here is a code snippet:

```
// Template itself, assume that is has been loaded from file
var messageTemplate = 
@"Deleted Order Item Information
------------------------------------ 

Delete Date:    {{Date}}
Delete Comment: {{DeletedComment}}
… other text";

// Parses and compiles the template
var template = DotLiquid.Template.Parse(messageTemplate);

// Renders the output
var messageBody = template.Render(DotLiquid.Hash.FromAnonymousObject(
    // Parameters
    new {
        Date = DateTime.Today,
        DeletedComment = "Some Comment"
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

As they say it is: "A templating engine built upon Microsoft's Razor parsing technology."

Quick example:

```
var modelData = new { Name = "Cookie Monster", Message = "Cookieees!!!" };
string template = "@Model.Name says: '@Model.Message'";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, modelData);

//result: Cookie Monster  says: 'Cookieees!!!'
```

And of course you can have razor script files (*.cshtml) and maybe use them something like this:

```
    var modelData = new { Name = "Cookie Monster", Message = "Cookieees!!!" };
    string template = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("~/templates/template.cshtml")).ReadToEnd();
    string result = Razor.Parse(template, modelData);
```